# Can I have different frequencies on different pins on Raspberry pi?

Tags: measuring

I am trying to configure two pins on Raspberry pi 4 with different frequencies (one being half of the other). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What frequencies?  What dutycycle?  What accuracy?

Comment: @joan One using 10Hz and the other using 20Hz. With duty cycle 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) using any of GPIO 0-31.

As an example using GPIO 5 and 6.

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

pigs pfs 5 10 # set GPIO 5 to 10 Hz frequency
pigs pfs 6 20 # set GPIO 6 to 20 Hz frequency

pigs p 5 128 # 128/256 square wave
pigs p 6 128 # 128/256 square wave
```

[pigs pfs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#PFS)
[pigs p](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#P/PWM)

[image]

C

[gpioPWM](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioPWM)

[gpioSetPWMfrequency](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetPWMfrequency)

Python

[set_PWM_dutycycle](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_dutycycle)

[set_PWM_frequency](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#set_PWM_frequency)